# How should I responsibly backup my heroku/s3/github based application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, backup

I have a rails app that runs on Heroku using their standard postgres database with images hosted on s3.

How should I responsibly do backups?

So far I download my application code, s3 files, and database snapshot monthly and store it on an external drive. Downloading my files from s3 is extremely slow and I expect it will get much much worse as time goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using the PG Backups Heroku add-on:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

It backs up your postgres database and can be configured to store the backups daily (or more often if need be). I'd recommend it in general for basic backups of the database.

The code I'd simply keep a copy of in a repository in github (or some other git repository). Github is great and I can't think of a reason to do anything else.

S3 itself is pretty safe and reliable. Here's an excerpt from their product information:

> Amazon S3 provides a highly durable storage infrastructure designed for mission-critical and primary data storage. Objects are redundantly stored on multiple devices across multiple facilities in an Amazon S3 Region. To help ensure durability, Amazon S3 PUT and COPY operations synchronously store your data across multiple facilities before returning SUCCESS.

If it were important that you have a secure copy of all your files from S3, I'd likely set up some sort of a regularly scheduled batch job to copy them to a server I could then backup separately. I've used the **S3 Tools** to do this in the past:

http://s3tools.org/s3cmd

Comment: Those are good suggestions and is similar to what I'm doing now. I suppose having code on github and locally is pretty good. I'll probably continue to download and store heroku backups to be extra safe. S3 is the biggest problem and using a scheduled task is probably the way to go for that, thanks!

Comment: So basically, your whole web-service relies on Amazon ... What if they're down for a quite long time for any reason, or they suddenly start to loose data? What if your whole business is relying on this?

Comment: `s3cmd` is *broken* and should not used for backups or anything automated. Most notably the 1.1.0 version and possibly anything older can return exit code `0` on `s3cmd put` even though it couldn't even resolve the hosts in case of a DNS failure.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to archive a site where access to the git repo used to push it was not readily available. I did the following using the heruku cli.

- heroku login
- heroku git:clone -a your-app-name
- heroku pg:backups:capture -a your-app-name
- heroku pg:backups:download -a your-app-name

When done you'll have a directory of the code and a database dump titled 'latest.dump' that I recommend you rename to include the app-name.

All of this would be fairly easy to script.

Answer (score 0):

For automated backups you only need to configure [heroku-db-backup-s3](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/devsenexx/heroku-db-backup-s3%20heroku-db-backup-s3%20buildpack) buildpack. And reschedule it as it show in the documentation.